# How to db.getUser() using go mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, bson, mongo-go-driver

I want to get the user details for a db using go driver.

For ex. in mongoshell

```
> db.getUser("testuser")
null
```

How do i construct a bson.M or bson.D for this ?

I don't want to pass additional args just retrieve the userinfo of a db

```
var op bson.M
command := bson.D{{"getUser", 1}, {"username", "testuser"}}
err = clientInfo.Database(db).RunCommand(context.TODO(), cmd).Decode(&op)
```

I tried something like above but it was returning the below error:

```
(CommandNotFound) no such command: 'getUser'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Database.RunCommand()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.RunCommand) is to facilitate calling MongoDB's [`runCommand()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/db.runCommand/) function, that is, it's a helper to run specified [database commands](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/command/).

That said, the `getUser()` function you call in the mongo shell is a function, not a command.

But there's a [`usersInfo`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/command/usersInfo/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.usersInfo) command which gets you the same data. Its syntax is:

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     usersInfo: <various>,
     showCredentials: <Boolean>,
     showCustomData: <Boolean>,
     showPrivileges: <Boolean>,
     showAuthenticationRestrictions: <Boolean>,
     filter: <document>,
     comment: <any>
   }
)
```

This is how you can execute this `usersInfo` command:

```
var op bson.M
cmd := bson.D{{Key: "usersInfo", Value: bson.M{
    "user": "testuser",
    "db":   "admin",
}}}
err = clientInfo.Database(db).RunCommand(ctx, cmd).Decode(&op)
```

Note that the `usersInfo` document has [various specifications](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/command/usersInfo/#std-label-usersInfo-field-specification), for example:

> ```
> { usersInfo: 1 }
> ```
>
> Returns information about the users in the database where the command is run.
> `mongosh` provides the `db.getUsers()` helper for this invocation of the command.
>
> ```
> { usersInfo: <username> }
> ```
>
> Return information about the a specific user that exists in the database where the command is run.
> `mongosh`provides the `db.getUser()` helper for this invocation of the command.
>
> ```
> { usersInfo: { user: <name>, db: <db> } }
> ```
>
> Returns information about the user specified by the name and database.
>
> ```
> { usersInfo: [ { user: <name>, db: <db> }, ... ] }
> { usersInfo: [ <username1>, ... ] }
> ```
>
> Returns information about the specified users.
>
> ```
> { forAllDBs: true }
> ```
>
> Returns information about users in all databases.

As you can see, the `getUser()` command is a shorthand for `{ usersInfo: <username> }` which you can call like this:

```
var op bson.M
cmd := bson.D{{Key: "usersInfo", Value: "testuser"}}
err = clientInfo.Database(db).RunCommand(ctx, cmd).Decode(&op)
```

You can of course use an array if you want info about multiple users:

```
cmd := bson.D{{Key: "usersInfo", Value: []string{"testuser", "anotheruser"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks @icza I want to check whether if a specific user exist in a db , if not then create a user can you help me with that ?  say if the user ` users:[]` then based on that i want to create user .

Comment: Run a [`createUser`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/command/createUser/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.createUser) command if the user doesn't exist.